# Why is Parse Server saveEventually with callback taking so long?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse Server for my Android app and everything is working fine, but every time I call `saveEventually` on a new or old `ParseObject`, it is taking a really long time. Sometimes it's more than 1 minute for 1 item to return the callback.

Anyone had this problem?

Example:

```
orderObject.p.apply {
      put(ORDER_STATE, ORDER_STATE_FINISHED)
      put(ORDER_NEXT_DATE, orderEndDate)
}

createLog("FinishOrderSeq", "OrderActivity - saveOrder - before saveEvent")
orderObject.p.saveEventuallyEx(isOnline(this)){ e ->
     createLog("FinishOrderSeq", "OrderActivity - saveOrder - after saveEvent")
     if (e == null){
         createToast(getString(R.string.order_dialog_success), this)
         createOrderCopy(orderObject, dialog)
     } else {
         createToast(getString(R.string.order_dialog_err), this)
         changeButtonState(posBtn, true)
         changeButtonState(negBtn, true)
     }
}

fun ParseObject.saveEventuallyEx(isOnline: Boolean, callback: (ParseException?) -> Unit){
    if (isOnline){
        saveEventually{ err ->
            callback(err)
        }
    } else {
        saveEventually()
        callback(null)
    }
}
```

Also logs as I replaced it with `saveInBackground` with callback(still 30 seconds):

```
2020-05-28 14:53:49.805 18673-18673/? I/FinishOrderSeq: OrderActivity - saveOrder - before saveEvent
2020-05-28 14:54:15.694 18673-18673/? I/FinishOrderSeq: OrderActivity - saveOrder - after saveEvent
```

**UPDATE:**
So I figured out from parse dashboard, that `ParseObject` is saved as record in table immediatelly, but callback from `saveEventually` is sent after 30sec - 2 minutes.

**UPDATE 2:**
I also tried to use `saveInBackground()` if user is online (with callback). This also took **30seconds to 2 minutes** for callback to return. Object was saved to parse database with all data after **100ms** (checked from Parse Dashboard).

Then I thought something is wrong with ParseSDK threads, so I used `save()` inside `Coroutine`. Same problem occured here, `save()` took **up to 2 minutes** to perform.

Code with coroutine:

```
fun ParseObject.saveAsync(context: CoroutineContext, scope: CoroutineScope, isOnline: Boolean, callback: (ParseException?) -> Unit){
    if (isOnline){
        scope.launch {
            var ex: ParseException? = null
            try {
                save()
            } catch (e: ParseException){
                ex = e
            }
            withContext(context){
                callback(ex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is some serious problem with callbacks in `ParseSDK` for `Android` and I don't know what can cause this. No exception no error on server side.

**UPDATE 3:**
After deeper investigation, I found which function is taking long time to proceed.

```
ParseObject.State result = saveTask.getResult();
```

Approximately **30 seconds - 2 minutes** to get into next line of code.
This is lowest level of function I can get inside SDK.

Inside function `save()` or `saveInBackground()` there is this inner function in Java:

```
Task<Void> saveAsync(final String sessionToken, final Task<Void> toAwait) {
        if (!isDirty()) {
            return Task.forResult(null);
        }

        final ParseOperationSet operations;
        synchronized (mutex) {
            updateBeforeSave();
            validateSave();
            operations = startSave();
        }

        Task<Void> task;
        synchronized (mutex) {
            // Recursively save children

            /*
             * TODO(klimt): Why is this estimatedData and not... I mean, what if a child is
             * removed after save is called, but before the unresolved user gets resolved? It
             * won't get saved.
             */
            task = deepSaveAsync(estimatedData, sessionToken);
        }

        return task.onSuccessTask(
                TaskQueue.<Void>waitFor(toAwait)
        ).onSuccessTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<ParseObject.State>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<ParseObject.State> then(Task<Void> task) {
                final Map<String, ParseObject> fetchedObjects = collectFetchedObjects();
                ParseDecoder decoder = new KnownParseObjectDecoder(fetchedObjects);
                return getObjectController().saveAsync(getState(), operations, sessionToken, decoder);
            }
        }).continueWithTask(new Continuation<ParseObject.State, Task<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Void> then(final Task<ParseObject.State> saveTask) {
                ParseObject.State result = saveTask.getResult();  <--- THIS IS TAKING LONG TIME
                return handleSaveResultAsync(result, operations).continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<Void>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Void> then(Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isFaulted() || task.isCancelled()) {
                            return task;
                        }

                        // We still want to propagate saveTask errors
                        return saveTask.makeVoid();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#saving-objects-offline):

> Most save functions execute immediately, and inform your app when the save is complete. If you don’t need to know when the save has finished, you can use `saveEventually` instead.

It can take a long time because with `saveEventually` you are basically saying "save it soon". If you want to "save it as soon a possible" then use `saveInBackground` as described in the [docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#saving-objects).

Further it says:

> All calls to saveEventually (and deleteEventually) are executed in the order they are called, so it is safe to call saveEventually on an object multiple times. If you have the local datastore enabled, then any object you saveEventually will be pinned as long as that save is in progress. That makes it easy to retrieve your local changes while waiting for the network to be available.

Which means that you can save and modify the object locally multiple times and the latest version will be stored in the database as soon as the network connection is reestablished.

Comment: And will it work if user is offline? Because my App has to work without internet connection. It should be stored locally, because in offline mode i can modify this object multiple times and possibly delete it till user will have connection available.

Comment: Also I need to work with that item immediately. That means I want to save it fast (to local datastore if offline, to server if online) and move to other part. User is waiting there for 1 minute on loading screen to continue. I need to reduce it to max 2 seconds. 1 minute is unacceptable time to save 1 object if you have local datastore.

Comment: Yes, see the addition to my answer. You can find all that information in the docs.

Comment: I tried saveInBackground and it is taking long time as I updated post. But I dont know how to fix it. Saving one ParseObject 30 seconds is weird

Comment: If you call `saveInBackground` *without* internet connection then the request will timeout and the save operation will fail and not be retried. If you call `saveInBackground` *with* internet connection then the issue can be anywhere between client -> server -> database.

Comment: Both saveInBackground and safeEventually are slow in my App. Thats the only Parse functions which are slowing down things. Other requests like queries are fast. I have search query where you type stuff and it will return like 100 items in less than second for example. Its like 700ms difference between ParseQuery call and response

Comment: As I said, the path is `client -> server -> database`. You can look at each checkpoint when the save request arrives and how long it takes to process to determine where the bottleneck is. If you use a load balancer and proxy server you'll have more checkpoints. You could start by lookin at the database and see how long the write request takes to process. If it always takes 30s to save the object, check whether the save is actually sucessfull, because that looks more like a timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214844/discussion-between-manuel-and-martin1337).